# Connection Mongo with Robot 3t

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to connect to Mongodb with Robot 3t on 5000 port.
But when I tried to connect me I have an error and I don't understand why.

I hope that someone could help me...
[this is my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYaBq.png)

[This is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZDu0.png)

Comment: Can you show how you us how you've started the MongoDB server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you start MongoDB service at 5000 port if not so connect it to 27017 port.
MongoDB service has default port i.e. 27017

Comment: This is actually more of a comment than an answer :)